# How to interpret a strange formula about $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

I obtained a strange formula about $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-(2\pi)^s&\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0} (-i\rho)^{-s}(2\pi)^{-\rho} e^{-i\pi \rho / 2} \Gamma(\rho)\;\;\text{ converges for } \Re(s)>1 \\ &\color{red}{\text{ and it extends analytically to } \Re(s)  >0}
\end{split} \label{1}\tag{1}
$$
In other words the generalized Dirichlet series $\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0} (2i\pi)^{-\rho}\Gamma(\rho) (\frac{\rho}{2i\pi})^{-s}$
has the same non-trivial poles as $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$, it encodes the Riemann hypothesis.

**I don't understand if it is obvious, expected, and how to categorize it in the zoo of Riemann zeta formulas. Would you have any insight?**

---

The proof of \eqref{1} is as follow: for $\Re(z)  >0$ let $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \Lambda(n) e^{-nz}$, so that
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} \Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty f(x)x^{s-1}dx,\quad\Re(s) > 1.
$$ We have the Mellin inversion and explicit formula, which converges without problems
$$
\begin{split}
f(z) &=\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{(2)} \frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} \Gamma(s) z^{-s}ds = \sum \Res\left(\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} \Gamma(s) z^{-s}\right)  \\
& = z^{-1}- \sum_\rho \Gamma(\rho) z^{-\rho}+
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \Res\left(\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} \Gamma(s) z^{-s},-k\right)
\end{split}$$
$\sum_\rho$ means sum over non-trivial zeros. $z^{-s}$ means $e^{-s \log z}$ with $\Im(\log z) \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Now $\int_\epsilon^\infty f(x)x^{s-1}dx$ is entire so for the Riemann hypothesis we are interested only in the behavior of $f(x)$ as $x\to 0^+$.

$f$ is $2i\pi$-periodic so we can look instead at the asymptotic of $f(2i\pi+x)$ as $x\to 0^+$. Because
$$
f'(z)= -\sum_{n\ge 1} \Lambda(n)ne^{-nz}=O\left(\sum_{n\ge 1} n e^{-n\Re(z)}\right)= O(1/\Re(z)^2)
$$ we get that
$$
f(2i\pi + x)=f(2i \pi e^{-i x/(2\pi)})+\int_{2i \pi e^{-i x/(2\pi)}}^{2i\pi + x}f'(z)dz= f(2i \pi e^{-i x/(2\pi)})+O(1).
$$
It happens that in the sum-over-residues series for
$f(2i \pi e^{-i x/(2\pi)})$ everything is $O(1)$ but
$$
g(x)=- \sum_{\Im(\rho)>0} \Gamma(\rho) (2i \pi e^{-i x/(2\pi)})^{-\rho}.
$$ Therefore, $\int_0^\epsilon (f(x)-g(x))x^{s-1}dx$ is analytic for $\Re(s) >0$ and due to exponential decay so is $\int_0^\infty (f(x)-g(x))x^{s-1}dx$ which is what \eqref{1} says.

Comment: Maybe $\frac{\zeta’(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\frac{d\ln(\zeta(s))}{ds}$, integrate to find the series of $\ln(\zeta(s))$ and take $\exp()$ on both sides to make the sum into a product?

Comment: Is there a typo in formula (1)? Should $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-...$ be $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=...$?

Comment: @StevenClark No

Comment: If your answer to the question of @StevenClark is "No" then what you are asking is quite unclear: The formula for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ is the expression $$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-(2\pi)^s\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0} (-i\rho)^{-s}(2\pi)^{-\rho} e^{-i\pi \rho / 2} \Gamma(\rho)\quad\text{?}$$  Meaning that $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ is equal to expression? Implying that $$(2\pi)^s\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0} (-i\rho)^{-s}(2\pi)^{-\rho} e^{-i\pi \rho / 2} \Gamma(\rho) = 0 \quad\text{?}$$

Comment: I thought perhaps there was a typo since the title implies the question is about a strange formula for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$. The only formula I see for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ is $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=-\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\ x^{s-1}dx,\ \Re(s)>1$ where $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\ge 1} \Lambda(n)\ e^{-n x}$ which doesn't seem to qualify as strange.

Comment: @LeeMosher  the function $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-(2\pi)^s\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0} (-i\rho)^{-s}(2\pi)^{-\rho} e^{-i\pi \rho / 2} \Gamma(\rho)$ is analytic for $\Re(s) > 0$. ie. the generalized Dirichlet series $(2\pi)^s\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0} (-i\rho)^{-s}(2\pi)^{-\rho} e^{-i\pi \rho / 2} \Gamma(\rho)$ has the same poles as $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$.

Comment: Ah. I wondered about the grammar in the first displayed line... : in my brand of U.S. English, I'd delete the "which" to get the sense you want.

Comment: Ah great, that all makes more sense now.